# IF formula - EXCEL - obtain data from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am calculating the approximate cost per journey of our metro and country customers.

I need to know how to get cells H4:H42 to obtain the data from cell D43 which says "Metro driving" if the value is 1 OR the data from D45 which says "Country driving" if the value is 2.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are u lookin below one ?(place this formula in D4 cell)

Assuming that D43 = "Metro driving", and D45 = "Country driving", you could use the following:

```
=IF(H4=1,$D$43,IF(H4=2,$D$45,"Nothing Matched"))
```

Comment: thanks for the edit Andrew Edgecombe .. Its more clear now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple find and replace or the following formula:

`=CHOOSE($H4,$D$43,$D$45)`

This gets the value in H and assigns D43 for 1, D45 for 2, and so on if you were to add more values for 3+.